# How to resolve project library via own mvn repository (artifactory)

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, setup-project

How can I link an maven repository that we set up internally with my Intellij?

In the project libraries view, I am able to add a new project library that resides in the standard maven reppositories but I do not see how to point IntelliJ to a specifiy maven repository, for example the artifactory that we set up for the company.

Settings.xml is also not recognized by Intellij. I post the settings.xml afterwards, it's not recognized though (password, username and company name have been replaced) :

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <username>USER</username>
            <password>PW</password>
            <id>central</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>
https://dev.mycompany.com:8443/artifactory/any
            </url>
            <id>central</id>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots />
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>
https://dev.mycompany.com:8443/artifactory/libs
                    </url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots />
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>
https://dev.mycompany.com:8443/artifactory/plugins
                    </url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <id>artifactory</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Why don't you define a new repo in your `pom.xml` ? IntelliJ will fetch it just fine

Comment: I'd like to do that, but the current project is an old monolithic legacy ant project. Fancy things like pom.xml etc. do currently not exist. 

Of course I could find a workaround but on the other hand I'd also like to tell IntelliJ to use the internal maven repository instead.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ uses repositories from `pom.xml` for your maven project and `settings.xml`, your maven configuration file. In order to get dependencies from repote repository and by not adding `pom.xml`, I believe you should define repository in settings file.

By default, this file is located in your home folder like `{home}/.m2/settings.xml`

Try add this configuration:

```
<settings>
 ...
 <profiles>
   ...
   <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>my-repo2</id>
         <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
   ...
 </profiles>

 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
 ...
</settings>
```

Also remember that you should either use profile while using maven or make it active by default. See more information [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

Comment: Thx for the answer! I enhanced my initial post because actually we are doing this already, but IntelliJ does not recognize the settings.xml